# Solving a non-homogeneous second-order differential equation with constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am given this equation:
$$
y''(x) y(x) - 4 y(x) = -4e^{4x}
$$
And I am asked to start off by finding the solution to the homogeneous equation.

First, I am confused as to why the above equation is said to be constant coefficient. Wouldn't the $y''(x)$ being multiplied to $y(x)$ mean that it is not a constant coefficient equation? But, our teacher did not teach us how to solve for equation that are not constant coefficient, and strictly said that we will not look at those equations now.

I went on to solve for the homogeneous solution by equating the right hand side of the equation to zero.
I got the characteristic equation: $q^2 -4=0$, $\longrightarrow$ $q=+2$ or $-2$.

So, i then got that the general homog. solution is: $Ae^{2t} + Be^{-2t}$, for $A,B$ constants.

But, this is wrong.

Comment: If the equation is printed like that and the task treats it like a linear ODE then it is a misprint. Either ask your teacher for a correction or, if that is not possible, solve $y''-4y=-4e^{4x}$ instead.

Comment: It is not with constant coefficient, are you sure about the equation?

Comment: Yes, that is the equation that I was given, and the question claims that it is a second-order DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: @gimusi : As a polynomial in $y,y',y''$, the coefficients on the left side are constant. It only does not help much as the equation is not linear.

Comment: And with the hint to look for the "solution to the homogeneous equation", the task claims that the equation is linear, which it is not. Faulty task.

Comment: Probably you have made a typo!